# How to enable double sided normals or double sided faces for rendering in python API?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

How to enable double-sided normal rendering in the python API of blender?

Comment: Do you mean the *Double Sided* checkbox in *Properties > Data > Normals*?

Comment: thank for the response. Yes , I mean that only for imported meshes.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`Mesh.show_double_sided`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=show_double_sided#bpy.types.Mesh.show_double_sided) flag to `True` for all mesh objects:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        obj.data.show_double_sided = True
```

Alternatively you can iterate through the [mesh data blocks](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.meshes) and set the flag:

```
import bpy

for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
    mesh.show_double_sided = True
```